# Dynamically load controller without templateURL and ngView

Tags: angularjs, url-routing

I don't want to use templateUrl, due to the way the app is currently structured.
I want to be able to dynamically load a controller into my ng-controller template.

I would think there would be a way to pass variable to ng-controller as you can see
I'm passing controller to ng-controller ignorantly hoping the name controller is assigned
to index_projects.

Routing

```
    config = (http,route) ->
      http.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token']     = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
      http.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest"
      route_to = (path,controller)->
        route.when path, {controller: controller}
      route_to '/projects', 'index_projects'
```

Template

```
.projects_wrap{ ng:{controller:'controller'} }
  %h2
    %span All Projects
    .light_button{ ng:{click: 'pop.new()'} }
      %span.light_plus
      Add Project
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2441-Nested-Views-Routing-And-Deep-Linking-With-AngularJS.htm

I am successfully freed of using ngView with this article.